# How to get all the DOM hierarchy of webpage DOM

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'd like to create a hierarchic view of the dom of a webpage.

For example this webpage :

```
<body>
      <div class="A"> </>
      <div class="B"> 
          <div class="C"> </>
      </>
```

I would like a result such as this

```
node             parent_node
body  
div class="A"    body
div class="B"    body
div class="C"    div class="B"
```

I tried to use scrapy with xpath

```
 for mytable in response.xpath("//*"):
        yield {
            'node': mytable,
            'parent': mytable.xpath("//parent::*")

        }
```

But It didn't work, it was doing a forever loop

Thanks for your help. I'dl like this to work for any webpage (so I've no info specific to one webpage)

---

Anderson terrific answer resolved it.

This is pretty good but there's still a slight issue.
Scrapy returns some weird stuff

```
<Selector xpath='//*' data=u'<span class="price">69,00\xa0\u20ac</span>'>
```

I'd prefer to get a cleaner result

```
<span class="price">69,00 €</span>
```

Comment: Try `"./parent::*"` instead of `"//parent::*"`

Comment: Awesome Andersson, worked like a charm. Many thanks